# Above or below number with ngclass Angular

Tags: angular, ng-class

I'm studying Angular. I'm training to change class if my variable is above ou below 0. It's possible to do something lile this ?

```
<li [ngClass]="{'list-group-item': true,
  'list-group-item-danger': loveIts < 0,
  'list-group-item-success': loveIts > 0}">

  <h4>{{postTitle}} -- {{postCreated_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy à hh:mm' | uppercase}}</h4>


</li>
```

If not, what is the good way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple conditions in ngClass - Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821875/multiple-conditions-in-ngclass-angular-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes is ok but you can also do in this way:

```
<li class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{
  'list-group-item-danger': loveIts < 0,
  'list-group-item-success': loveIts > 0}">

<h4>{{postTitle}} -- {{postCreated_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy à hh:mm' | uppercase}}</h4>
```