# How do dynamically position and size div elements?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to have an angular component that can dynamically position and resize div elements depending on how many div elements are to be displayed. [This is what I have achieved so far](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-24gbi5?file=src/app/app.component.css).

> EDIT: If you checkout my stackblitz example I am using display: flex
>   (thus flexbox). The issue I am having is how can I make sure that a
>   row will at most only have 3 divs and then wrap to the next line and
>   that the divs length will always be the same?

.

> EDIT 2: My goal is that when there is one or two divs the length of
>   the div is half that of the container. That is why I put a 'ruler' at
>   the top in the image below. If there are more than 2 divs the length
>   of the divs should be 1/3 of the length of the container. And a row
>   should be filled by three divs before wrapping to the next row.

Below is a visual representation of what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

All the divs in a particular set are of the same width and height.

I see how I can hack around by using `calc()` in width but then I will have to pass the number of divs variable to my css file. Also I am aware that using [Multiple conditions in ngClass - Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821875/multiple-conditions-in-ngclass-angular-4) is an option, but I would like to use that if I did not have any other option.

How can I achieve what I am trying to achieve with css only (if possible)? If it is not possible to use css only I will gladly take any other recommendation.

Comment: Have you considered using a stylistic package like bootstrap? Or using `display: flex` ? Or using a directive rather than a full component?

Comment: My current example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-24gbi5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) I am using `display: flex`.

Comment: Definitely, use flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation, and have you considered bootstrap (It is a CSS package)? @YulePale,

Comment: @DaneBrouwer My current implemetation is static not dynamic. If I reduce the div elements to one it won't work as I want it to. From what I am seeing, I think I will have to use ng-class with multiple conditions. My problem is not that flexbox is not working, it is. My problem is that I am trying to make it dynamic.

Comment: You could use `min-width: calc(100%/3.1);`?

Comment: @DaneBrouwer I have tried that. Still not getting my desired results. I will just use conditional classes and see how it goes if it works I will post the answer here. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @YulePale, Can you check my answer for your issues https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-24gbi5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @YulePale [Found a link that might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has)

Comment: @Kitta It works, but not completely. My goal is that when there is one div or two divs the size of the div is half that of the container.

Comment: @YulePale, can checkout my update link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utfkgg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** make `flex` container with

```
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

**Second** use `calc()` to specify items width

```
.item {
  width: calc(33.33% - 0px);
}
```

**Third** specify first and second child behavior. They should grow, but `max-width: 50%`

```
.item:first-child, .item:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  outline: dashed red 1px;
  margin: 10px 0
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
  width: calc(33.33% - 0px);
}

.item:first-child, .item:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Checkout sample working copy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utfkgg) Check the **flex** will slove the above issues i guess.

```
.parent {
  display:flex; 
  justify-content:space-around; 
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.option-box{
  width:40%;
  border: 1px blue solid;
  margin: 3px
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 301px) {
  .option-box {
    width:30%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .option-box {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

[image: Flex]

[image]