# [ng-class]Add multiple classes with a single condition

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-class

Is it possible to add **multiple classes** with `[ng-class]` with **a single condition**?

Something like this:

```
<div [ngClass]="Cond ? 'class1, class2' : 'class3, class4'"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple conditions in ngClass - Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44821875/multiple-conditions-in-ngclass-angular-4)

Comment: @DanielHabenicht No, I want a single condition only. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As specified in:
https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description
You can:
`<some-element [ngClass]="{'class1 class2 class3' : true}">...</some-element>`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```html
<div [ngClass]="{'class1 class2' : condition, 'class3': !condition"}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost right, just  ditch the commas:

```
<div [ngClass]="Cond ? 'class1 class2' : 'class3 class4'"></div>
```

Try it on stackblitz.com - [I wrote an example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-laz45q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy.
Steps

1. Create a boolean for controlling the class binding condition

`public hasError: boolean = false;`

2. Create an object with class names as follows

```
public classObj: any = {
    "classA": !this.hasError,
    "classB": this.hasError,
    "classC": !this.hasError,
    // how much ever class you want
}
```

3. Finally use ngClass directive for binding the `classObj`

`<h2 [ngClass]="classObj">Hey, I have a lot of classes!</h2>`